# Attach floated div to bottom without knowing its width

Tags: html, css

I have a div containing some text that is left floated so it can appear to the right of an image, and they're all wrapped in a container. However, I can't make the text attach to the bottom of the container. If I use `position: relative` on the container and `position: absolute; bottom: 0` on the div containing the text, which works in most cases, the text starts rendering over the image.

Here is what I have now:

http://jsfiddle.net/RWkjL/

In short, what I want is to make this:

[image]

To look like this:

[image]

... without knowing the text's width.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved using `vertical-align` in CSS.

### HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://www.purac.com/_sana_/handlers/getfile.ashx/5671e36e-6ba3-4ffc-9b58-8495cc024bfa/Sample-grey.png" />
    <p id="text">
        Lorem ipsum <br/>
        dolor sit amet
    </p>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#container {
    height: 128px;
}

img, #text {
    vertical-align:bottom;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is [an updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RWkjL/3/).

You can read more about `vertical-align` [here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/) if you need more control over it. You can specify a specific length for the vertical align to be at as well, using any CSS length unit.

**Edit**: Because there's no more floating, you can drop the definition of the height of the container. It is also worth noting that setting `overflow: hidden;` on `#container` would also prevent the issue of 0 height in a parent element that has only floating children.

Comment: Nice! Works like a charm

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please accept it. Just wanted to add that because you are not floating everything anymore, it's no longer necessary to define the height of the container, so the code can be simplified even further. I will edit it to reflect this change.

Answer (score 0):

While randak's answer is totally correct, this is another solution to your problem:

```
#container {
    height: 128px;
    position:relative;
}

#picture {
    float: left;
}

#text {
    float: left;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:128px;
}
```